# Static Cells are showing empty in Interface Builder (running XCode 7.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

I'm running Xcode 7.1 on OS 10.11.1. I have several tableviews with static cells. For cells that are below the size for the view controller, the data (labels, text fields, etc) of the static cells don't appear. The static cells will not show any saved data. If I scroll or do anything else, the static cells are all empty.

I can still see the static cells when I run the simulator, I just cannot edit the cells in interface builder.

Has anyone found a workaround for this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem.
But I tried to add cells between the old ones, which messed up everything.
The TableView didn't resize the contentSize on runtime and draws the cells on top of each other. 
Restored the storyboard from Git now and download Xcode 7.0 for some more testing.

Comment: @thyraz - where you able to get things working with Xcode 7.0? I downloaded Xcode 6.4 and that has been only a temporary fix b/c Xcode 6.4 has issues uploading to Testflight.

Comment: yes, Xcode 7.0.1 fixed it for me.

Comment: Same problem in latest version 7.1.1

Comment: I filed a bug report w/ Apple. I'll need to follow up with them.

Answer (score 7):

Finally found a workaround, as this still happens in Xcode 7.2 Beta:
In the Interface Builder select the View Controller and set it's simulated size to "Freeform" in the attributes inspector, then switch to the size inspector and set a height that fits the whole content.

To be honest, this is way better than having to scroll.
Guess this will become my default setup for static tableviews in the IB. :)

[image: screenshot]